# Stripe API with Rails, ERROR "publishable key sent, but only secret keys can be used"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I'm trying to understand this error. I have my api keys correct in my stripe.rb and also in my devise.rb. Is there an obvious reason I'm receiving this error which I can't see?
Image below.

[Console output of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iosoO.png)

Comment: Without your code it's hard to figure out exactly what is going on... but it sounds like you are using a publishable key for backend requests. Changing it to use a secret key should fix the problem. But again, providing your code would be helpful...

Comment: No images of text, please.

Answer (score 2):

Making any kind of charge with Stripe is a two-step process.

1. You collect your customer's credit card information with a Checkout, Elements, or mobile SDK based-form, the card details are securely sent to Stripe. In return Stripes send back a token that you can use to charge this card. For this operation you use your **publishable key** (pk_test_xxxyyyzz).
2. You take this token and tell Stripe to make a charge, create a customer, etc. This is where your backend rails code comes in, and to do anything here you need to use your **secret key** (sk_test_xxxyyyzz).

To know specifically what's wrong here, we'd need to see code, but from the error, it looks like you're trying to use a publishable key for **#2**, where you need to be using a secret key!